# Data deleted from kafka topics

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

The topics that I had started yesterday are not having any data. The topics appear in the list command but all data is lost. The data was produced and saved in the topic. However, after a period that I dont know, the data is gone. It should be noted that I did consume the data once.

How?
What settings should I change?

Comment: This is far too vague for anyone to be able to help you. You need to add more info. Can you produce successfully? Were you ever able to consume? Is it just yesterday's data that you're unable to consume now?

Comment: done, made teh changes.

Comment: By default Kafka writes to /tmp filesystem. If you restarted your computer, that data is just gone

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to consumer using the same consumer group and that group's offsets are not expired yet then you will not get anything back.

If you are not consuming as part of the same consumer group, perhaps topic data is expired and deleted?

You can check the start and end offset of topic; e.g.

```
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-orders --time -2
bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic test-orders --time -1
```

If reported start and end offsets match there is no data in the topic. In that case, you can take a look at `retention.ms` at topic or broker level. Increasing the value of this config would keep the records longer at the expense of using additional disk space.